# Call to function "templatefile" failed: contents of "modules/ec2/.././b.ps1" are not valid UTF-8; use the filebase64 function to obtain the Base64

Tags: terraform

```
    data "cloudinit_config" "ec2_user_data" {
      part {
        filename     = "a.ps1"
        content_type = "text/x-shellscript"
        content = templatefile("${path.module}/../scripts/a.ps1", {
            computername       = var.computername
          })
      }
      part {
        filename     = "b.ps1"
        content_type = "text/x-shellscript"
          content = templatefile("${path.module}/../scripts/b.ps1", {
             computername       = var.computername
          })
      }
    }
```

When i made terraform validate i am getting:

> Call to function "templatefile" failed: contents of "modules/ec2/../scripts/b.ps1" are not valid UTF-8; use the filebase64 function to obtain the Base64 encoded │ contents or the other file functions (e.g. filemd5, filesha256) to obtain file hashing results "

i tried to put templatefile(filebase64 ("${path.module}/../scripts/b.ps1)" but the error is then:

> Invalid value for "path" parameter: open
> The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

Also tried using file funtions but again same error, if i put a.ps1 instead of b.ps1 it is working. so i guess it is something inside the file but i don't know what and how to parse it. Just know if it is executed manually it is working.
Any suggestions?

Comment: It should be `filebase64(templatefile(...))`, not the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

something was wrong with the file i have created new one encoded and verification passed.
Get-Content -Path .\b.ps1 | out-file -encoding utf8 "b1.ps1"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).